# How to create separate registration form for Subscriber level in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, membership, custom-wordpress-pages

How to create a registration page(signup page) for subscriber level(which is one of the 4 user levels in wordpress), currently i have a sign up form for Author level.

Answer (score 0):

Already you have sign up form for author level, so it is very much easy. You just clone the author level form ,then change the role parameter
 role =>'author' to 'subscriber'.